# Django app not populating data from admin - Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy my first django app to heroku. Everything is fine, but my app is not populating data from admin. When I check admin page of app it has data, but same does not reflect on app. What could be the issue.
Its been hours I m fiddling with this.

this is my settings.py

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DEBUG = False

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

## post_list.html

```
{{posts}}
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
from django.utils import timezone

def post_list(request):
 posts =   Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by("published_date") 
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {"posts":posts} )
```

Comment: please show us how you configured your DB. You are using PostGre? Are you sure you don't have the local DB activated in production? In general there are a lot of reasons for that but that is my first guess.

Comment: @hansTheFranz I have updated with settings.py

Comment: is the data getting saved when you click save in the admin? or any error is shown? and also post the concerned view and template where the data should be populated

Comment: @Exprator - updated code with view.py and post_list.html. Code is working fine for local and when in production html part is rendered perfectly but database is empty and no error is being thrown

Comment: what does it show now in the page? blank totally?

Comment: Have you checked the logs of your server?

Comment: @eyllanesc yup checked.. no error there too

Comment: And the database?

Comment: In admin I can see recently insrted data @ey

Comment: do one thing just change the query to Post.objects.all() and check if posts get rendered

Comment: @Exprator that worked.. but I dont really get that..This query was working fin for local data..

Comment: i guess the problem is with timezone.now() its better to use datetime.now as timezone might be a problem with the heroku server

Comment: can you post your models.py

Comment: @Exprator thanks a ton ..you saved my day

Comment: glad could help @Payal